# How to Change the Y axis of an Primefaces 7.0 ChartJS Linechart with Java?

Tags: primefaces, chart.js

With the new version of Primefaces (7.0) the jqplot-charts got replaced by ChartJS Charts. Now I want the Y-Axis of my chart to be longer. With the old charts this was easily possible in Java but now I don't know how to do it. If it isn't possible in Java is there an alternative way to change the Y-Axis of an existing chart?

Comment: How did you solve this with PF6? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I did not make the old version but in the old code it was solved this way: `medicationModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setMin(0);
            medicationModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y).setMax(
                listOfMedSeries.size() + 1);`

Comment: Are you saying this worked before and does not work with PF7 anymore? (for me it does)

Comment: yes because this getAxis stuff is part of org.primefaces.model.chart. but the new LineCharts need org.primefaces.model.charts.

Comment: the linecharts that can use this are imported with org.primefaces.model.chart.LineChartModel; but my linechartmodel comes from org.primefaces.component.linechart.LineChart; bzw org.primefaces.model.charts.line.LineChartModel;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all right in the showcase in the 2nd example for Cartesian Line Model.
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chartjs/line.xhtml

```java
   public void createCartesianLinerModel() {
        cartesianLinerModel = new LineChartModel();
        ChartData data = new ChartData();

        LineChartDataSet dataSet = new LineChartDataSet();
        List<Number> values = new ArrayList<>();
        values.add(20);
        values.add(50);
        values.add(100);
        values.add(75);
        values.add(25);
        values.add(0);
        dataSet.setData(values);
        dataSet.setLabel("Left Dataset");
        dataSet.setYaxisID("left-y-axis");

        LineChartDataSet dataSet2 = new LineChartDataSet();
        List<Number> values2 = new ArrayList<>();
        values2.add(0.1);
        values2.add(0.5);
        values2.add(1.0);
        values2.add(2.0);
        values2.add(1.5);
        values2.add(0);
        dataSet2.setData(values2);
        dataSet2.setLabel("Right Dataset");
        dataSet2.setYaxisID("right-y-axis");

        data.addChartDataSet(dataSet);
        data.addChartDataSet(dataSet2);

        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
        labels.add("Jan");
        labels.add("Feb");
        labels.add("Mar");
        labels.add("Apr");
        labels.add("May");
        labels.add("Jun");
        data.setLabels(labels);
        cartesianLinerModel.setData(data);

        //Options
        LineChartOptions options = new LineChartOptions();
        CartesianScales cScales = new CartesianScales();
        CartesianLinearAxes linearAxes = new CartesianLinearAxes();
        linearAxes.setId("left-y-axis");
        linearAxes.setPosition("left");
        CartesianLinearAxes linearAxes2 = new CartesianLinearAxes();
        linearAxes2.setId("right-y-axis");
        linearAxes2.setPosition("right");

        cScales.addYAxesData(linearAxes);
        cScales.addYAxesData(linearAxes2);
        options.setScales(cScales);    

        Title title = new Title();
        title.setDisplay(true);
        title.setText("Cartesian Linear Chart");
        options.setTitle(title);

        cartesianLinerModel.setOptions(options);
    }
```